# Excel VB Check boxes variables in Functions for Dynamic Form

Tags: vba, excel

Excel VB Check boxes variables in Functions for Dynamic Form

I work in a Project Management Office and every time a department asks us for some sort of a report. We then would get the data from our database and work hours to create the report which is inefficient.

What I did is, I copied all columns from the database into an excel sheet, then I created a form sheet which will show this data. Then a control sheet which has all the check boxes in them. Each check box represents a column, in example: Project Code, Project Title, Consultant Name, Project Budget, etc...

Now my idea was that, I have 2 groups of check boxes. 1- The normal check boxes which is linked directly to the database data as mentioned above.
2- form check boxes, which is like a grouped check boxes, in example, "Finance Form", "MD Board Form", etc... Choosing one of those will select multiple check boxes from group 1. Kind of like a reference, I then can customize and select more check boxes if I want to add more data.

Now in the form sheet I made this simple formula to extract the data:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(B$1),MATCH($A2,Project_ID,0)),"")
```

And I made the reference to be linked by the Project ID number as shown in the formula. Now this works fine. On column "A" I have the project IDs, then on the top row of the rest of the columns I have a drop down menu that is linked to the database headers. Each of the columns in the database sheet is named after the header.

Now here is the tricky part.
What I simply did is something like this:
for the Project Name check box I did:

```
Sub CB_Project_Name_Click()

If ActiveSheet.Shapes("CB_Project_Name").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
    For i = 0 To 99
        If IsEmpty(Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i)) Then
            Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value = "Project_Name"
            i = 99
        End If
    Next i
Else
    For i = 0 To 99
        If Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value = "Project_Name" Then
            Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value = ""
            i = 99
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

While this works fine... It's not really... Professional, then I did the same for couple more check boxes, but... I have over 100 check boxes and as I said this isn't professional.

So I am trying to workout a function to repeat the code but I can't seem to get it working. I used to work with C++ and I can use functions that doesn't have to return data (void), but this doesn't appear to be the case in VB.
I tried Sub and Function but apparently they both have to return an argument.

What I want to do is something like this:
if the database header name is "Project_Budget", then the check box is named CB_Project_Budget.

```
Sub CB_List(CB_Name As String, Name As String)
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("CB_Name").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
    For i = 0 To 99
        If IsEmpty(Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i)) Then
            Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value = "Name"
            i = 99
        End If
    Next i
Else
    For i = 0 To 99
        If Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value = "Name" Then
            Sheets("English").Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Value = ""
            i = 99
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Then I will use:

```
CB_List(CB_Project_Budget,Project_Budget)
```

But this gives me an error since it needs to return an argument.

As you can see, the most important thing is that I want the check box name when implemented in the function to be a variable (I know I implemented it wrong in the example above but that's only to illustrate what I want to do) as well as the value of the cell that I'm adding in the form sheet. I also want to know if its possible to string manipulate like in C++ so I can also just remove the "CB_" from the check box name and use it as the header name.

Then I have the other problem of sorting out my headers in order but that's for another time!

Sorry for the long post :) I tried to look for a similar problem on the forum but couldn't find... I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: "But this gives me an error since it needs to return an argument." This is because you are not using the right syntax for calling a `Sub` in VBA. Try `CB_List CB_Project_Budget, Project_Budget` without the parentheses.

Comment: oh wow... I feel silly.I
It worked, and even better, it does work as a variable in the function!
and for string manipulation I just used '("CB_" & name)'...

I'm wondering if I can make it even easier... that the function will work depending on the checkbox name instead!